# The cfi_* are not clear to me

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

### Update:

I could have parts of my answers there :
http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf

page 58.
Pffeeeew assembly is a tough language :)

#### Context:

Learning GAS assembly for 2-3 days now.
Linux 64 bits.

GCC 4.8.2

Compilation with **no optimization** (-O0 -march=native) to see the basic assembly generated.

#### Question:

***Is my explanation (below) right ?***

All my C converted code is composed the same way with

```
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
subq    $16, %rsp

#my code here

movl    $0, %eax
leave
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

I try to explain the steps :

1)

I read that the `cfi_def_cfa_offset` *has* to be 16 on 64 bits arch. That is a rule (**right ?**).

2)

`cfi_offset` and `cfi_def_cfa_register` are "associated" to the value 6. **Why ??**

3)

I understand that we skip the cfi_def_cfa_offset 16 bytes with the `subq`.

4)

But **why the `cfi_def_cfa 7, 8` in the end ?** it doesn't make sense to me because 8 appears nowhere. Why not `cfi_def_cfa 15, 16` by the way ?

Thanks

Comment: [Read this.](http://pix.cs.olemiss.edu/csci223/asX64Directives.txt)  I believe that `6` is the register number for `rbp` and `7` is `rsp`.  If you are writing the assembly yourself, you can use the register name such as `%rbp` instead of `6`.

Comment: Well done JS1, i could have my answers thanks to your pointers. I update the question accordingly. +1. By the way, grab some more rep if you make it an answer :)

Comment: In general you don't have to bother with `cfi` directives when writing assembly, unless you want very nice debugging.

Comment: Thanks Jester, that is a good point for me to know ;)